# Add Custom Controls and attributes to All New Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

Is there any way to change all of new forms and custom it ?
I want to set custom controls to all of my new forms , as example All of the forms have a PictureBox on top with a special picture , and all of the forms use an special font with default size ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Form that has all the features you want all of your forms to have (call this BaseForm or something similar).

Inherit from BaseForm for all of your other forms.

This should give you exactly what you are looking for.

Here's a good example:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/master-page-in-C-Sharp-window-forms/

Comment: Damn, Inheritance. Eh, I was close.